# How to display a Sudoku board in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I've written a code that solves Sudoku puzzles and the program outputs the solution to the console in a Sudoku-like way:

```
6 5 2 | 3 1 4 | 9 8 7
8 7 4 | 5 9 6 | 2 3 1
1 3 9 | 7 8 2 | 4 6 5
- - - | - - - | - - -
7 4 1 | 6 5 9 | 8 2 3
9 8 3 | 4 2 1 | 7 5 6
2 6 5 | 8 7 3 | 1 4 9
- - - | - - - | - - -
5 9 8 | 2 3 7 | 6 1 4
3 1 6 | 9 4 8 | 5 7 2
4 2 7 | 1 6 5 | 3 9 8
```

I also want to output this Sudoku board (a list containing 9 lists each containing 9 numbers) onto the screen with Kivy. How can I get the list "board" (witch is declared in Python) in my .kv file? I've used identifiers to get the input via TextInputs (in the .kv file). Can something similar be done with the board? (I write all my style code in a .kv file and the logic is done in a Python file.)

Comment: How do you want the board to look like on the screen?

Comment: Preferably in the sudoku-like way with the lines between the numbers